# Multiprocessing and scipy (dblquad)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, multiprocessing

I am trying to speed up the following code in python:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy import integrate
import camb
from tqdm import tqdm
import os

#Reading a PS
dir = os.getcwd()
data = np.loadtxt(dir+"/ps1-peacock.txt")
kh = data[:,0]
p_lin = data[:,1]
p_nlin = data[:,2]
p_linear = interpolate.interp1d(kh,p_lin)

#Integrand of P22
def upper_mu(x):
    return min(1.0,(kk**2 + np.exp(2*x))/(2*kk*np.exp(x)))


def lower_mu(x):
    return max(-1.0,-(kk**2+np.exp(x))/(2*kk*np.exp(x)))

def mulow(x):
  return max(-1.0,(kh[-1]**2.0-kk**2.0-np.exp(x)**2.0)/(-2.0*kk*np.exp(x)))

def muhigh(x):
  return min(1.0,(kh[0]**2.0-kk**2.0-np.exp(x)**2.0)/(-2.0*kk*np.exp(x)))

def f22(mu,q,k):
    r = np.exp(q)/k
    F = (7.0*mu+(3.0-10.0*mu**2)*r)/(14.0*r*(r**2-2.0*mu*r+1.0))
    psik = (k**2+np.exp(2*q)-2.0*k*mu*np.exp(q))**0.5
    
    if (psik>kh[0] and psik<kh[-1]):
        return 1.0/2.0/np.pi**2.0*np.exp(3*q)*p_linear(np.exp(q))*p_linear(psik)*F**2
    else:
        return 0

P22 = np.zeros_like(kh)
error = np.zeros_like(kh)

for i in tqdm(range(0,np.shape(kh)[0])):
    kk = kh[i]
    P22[i], error[i] = integrate.dblquad(f22,np.log(kh[0]),np.log(kh[-1]),mulow,muhigh,args=(kh[i],),epsrel=1e-3, epsabs=50)[:2]
```

Here follows the integral in text for reasons of clarity:

[image: photo]

I would like to use multiprocessing to improve the performance of `dblquad()`. Does anyone know how can I implement it in this specific case?

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing won't help here, you cannot split the dblquad work between python processes.

If you have several integrals to compute, then yes, you can split integrals between processes. Whether this is worth it strongly depends on the amount of work there is for each process.

Comment: But the integral for each value of k is independent (i.e for a fixed value of k there is a double integral to me computed). It makes me think that i could, for example, split the full range of integration into three parts and associate each one to a different process. Does it make sense?